# How to change font in the string only for the last two characters

Tags: swift, range, nsattributedstring, nsrange, nsmutableattributedstring

I have the string 0.1234
To find the last two characters I use string.suffix(2)
if I use NSRange to find this range in attributedString it works well until the string will not be with equals values. if the string would be like 1.1212, nsrange will be applied to the first found value (string.suffix(2) = 12 in this case)
so the formatting will be wrong.

How to change the font only for the last two characters.

[image]

Comment: Make sure your string has at least 2 characters and it true offset the string endIndex by -2

Comment: As @leo said, suffix of length 2 has index end-2. You can also play with length, prefix and suffix to get both parts...

Comment: This question actually has nothing to do with `NSAttributedString`, and everything to do with simple substring calculation.

Comment: @NRitH how to change font in string for last two characters without making it attributed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.Index` method

```
func index(_ i: String.Index, offsetBy n: String.IndexDistance, limitedBy limit: String.Index) -> String.Index?
```

on your `string.endIndex` with a negative offset of two and limited by your `string.startIndex`:

---

```
let string = "1.1212"
if let start = string.index(string.endIndex, offsetBy: -2, limitedBy: string.startIndex) {
    print(string[start..<string.endIndex])  // "12\n"
    // or using a partial range
    print(string[start...]) // "12\n"
}
```

---

Applying a smaller font size and color to it preserving the original label font:

Playground testing:

```
let string = "1.1212"
let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: string)

if let start = string.index(string.endIndex, offsetBy: -2, limitedBy: string.startIndex), let attrStr = label.attributedText {
    let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attrStr)
    mutableAttributedString.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red, NSAttributedString.Key.font: label.font.withSize(label.font.pointSize * 0.6)], range: .init(start..<string.endIndex, in: string))
    label.attributedText = mutableAttributedString
    label.sizeToFit()
}
```

Comment: and how to change font in this case for last two?

Comment: I see only one solution to make two uilabels with diffrent fonts

Answer (score 1):

**You can use this extension**

```
extension String {
    func attributedStringWithColorSize( color: UIColor, size:CGFloat = 12) -> NSAttributedString {
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self)


        if self.count < 3 {
            return attributedString
        }
            let range = NSRange(location: self.count-2, length: 2)
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font,value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: size) , range: range)
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: color, range: range)

        return attributedString
    }
}
```

Use like this

```
@IBOutlet weak var lab: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        lab.attributedText = "1.1470".attributedStringWithColorSize(color: UIColor.red , size: 15)
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

[image]

[image]